# What are the requirements of a kernel module to load by an application at runtime

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

Sometimes I have observed, when an application is run or calls any kernel module functions, respective kernel module is loaded automatically.

I want to build a similar kernel module which will be loaded automatically when my application executes and calls its ioctls.

Actually i want to know, what I need to write in my kernel module so that it will be loaded automatically by my application at runtime.

I looked for it a lot but didn't find anything that is satisfactory.

Answer (score 3):

The keyword to search for is `kmod`, being the part of the Linux kernel which handles requests for loading kernel modules on the fly.

There are too many details to list in an answer here, but have a look at [Linux Device Drivers, 2nd Edition' book, chapter 11](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch11.html) which goes into detail about kernel module autoloading.

Note that module load requests must come from within the kernel.  So, if you have a device driver in a custom module but it's not loaded, the kernel has no way of knowing how to match up an ioctl request to your driver.  But let's say you have a driver and some ioctl functions split into different modules A and B, it would be possible to insert the main module A to provide the device interface, and then when ioctls were requested of driver A, it could auto load the additional module B containing the ioctl functions using the kmod mechanism

Comment: +1 : Note `kmod` is fairly new and might not be standard on many currently deployed (2013) platforms.